# UDP Daytime service client getting no response

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, udp

I am struggling with following exercise from Python Core Application Programming by W. Chun:

> 2-6.  Daytime Service. Use the socket.getservbyname() to determine the port number for the “daytime” service under the UDP protocol. Check the documentation for getservbyname() to get the exact usage syntax (i.e., socket.getservbyname. **doc**). Now write an application that sends a dummy message over and wait for the reply. Once you have received a reply from the server, display it to the screen.

My code is apparently incorrect and I fail to understand why:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from socket import *

HOST = 'time.nist.gov'
PORT = getservbyname('daytime', 'udp')
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

udpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    udpCliSock.sendto('dummy message', ADDR)
    data, ADDR = udpCliSock.recvfrom(BUFSIZ)
    if not data:
        break
    print data

udpCliSock.close()
```

Thank you for your time in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is perfectly valid but there is no UDP service
at time.nist.gov.

If you use udpCliSock.connect(ADDR) first and then send() instead
of sendto(), you'll get a `connection refused` error.  This typically
means that nobody's listening.

This error is suppressed if sendto() is used (connectionless UDP...).

I tested your code against my own UDP classes from cpp-lib (https://github.com/gewesp/cpp-lib) and
it works perfectly well as long as the server actually replies.

NIST says:

2. Users of the NIST "DAYTIME" protocol on tcp port 13 are also strongly encouraged to upgrade to the network time protocol, which provides greater accuracy and requires less network bandwidth. The NIST time client (nistime-32bit.exe) supports both protocols. We expect to replace the tcp version of this protocol with a udp-based version near the end of 2013.

I read that as they're currently running TCP *only* and will switch to UDP as soon
as they get around to it.

http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

Comment: The error is not 'suppressed': it's just that it can't be routed to the socket because the OS doesn't know which socket caused it, unless there is one connected to the source of the ICMP message that causes it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 "time" protocol services each running on different ports:

| Service | Port | Protocol | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Daytime service | 13 | TCP and UDP | [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol) |
| Time service | 37 | TCP and UDP | [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Protocol) |
| Network Time Protocol (NTP) | 123 | UDP | [[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) |

**1. Using "daytime" service (port 13)**

The daytime UDP service (port 13) on *time.nist.gov* appears to be either disabled or a firewall is blocking the UDP packet response.

You can, however, call the DAYTIME TCP service to fetch the current time:

```python
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "time.nist.gov"
port = 13
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print(data.decode())
    else:
        break

s.close()
```

**Output:**

```
59373 21-06-08 17:03:08 50 0 0 535.1 UTC(NIST) *
```

**2. Using "time" service (port 37)**

The TIME service on UDP port 37 returns a 32-bit unsigned integer in binary format. You can convert the relative time in seconds from 1-Jan-1900 to a datetime object.

```python
port = 37
host = "time.nist.gov"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,     # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP

msg = "ask for time"
sock.sendto(msg.encode(), (host , port ))
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
print("received message: %s" % data)
sock.close()

# convert 32-bit unsigned integer in binary format to an integer
seconds = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='big')
print(f"seconds={seconds}")

dt = datetime(1900, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
print("rcv=", dt)
print("now=", datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

**Output:**

```
received message: b'\xe4j13'
seconds=3832164659
rcv=2021-06-08 18:21:43
now=2021-06-08 18:21:43
```

**3. Using Network Time Protocol (NTP) service (port 123)**

The NTP response packet has four times defined as follows:

1. orig = Originating local time at the client when the request departed for the server
2. recv = Receive time at the server when the request arrived from the client
3. tx = Transmit time at the server when the response left for the client
4. dest = local time the NTP message is received at the client

NTP differs from the other time protocols in that by having these 4 times, it is able to calculate the time offset (time difference between the two clocks) and round-trip delay (or latency).

```python
import ntplib

client = ntplib.NTPClient()
server = "time.nist.gov"

resp = client.request(server, version=3)

print("offset", resp.offset)
print("delay", resp.delay)

print("orig_time:", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(resp.orig_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
print("recv_time:", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(resp.recv_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
print("tx_time  :", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(resp.tx_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
print("dest_time:", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(resp.dest_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Output:

```
offset 0.004678010940551758
delay 0.06687116622924805

orig_time: 2021-06-10 19:07:52.410973
recv_time: 2021-06-10 19:07:52.449087
tx_time :  2021-06-10 19:07:52.449089
dest_time: 2021-06-10 19:07:52.477846
```